# Apache Poi, Xades Signature add Timestamp revocation info

Tags: java, apache-poi, digital-signature, xades

I am working with Apache Poi 5.1.0, I sign an **.docx** Document, and the signature is valid.

I add this code:

```
RevocationData revocationData = new RevocationData();
revocationData.addCRL(crl1);
.
.
.
revocationData.addCRL(crlN);
revocationData.addOCSP(ocspResp.getEncoded());

RevocationDataService revocationDataService = revocationChain -> revocationData;
    signatureConfig.setRevocationDataService(revocationDataService);
```

Where **revocationData** contains a  OCSPResp and all CRL files including the CRL for the TSP Chain.

But when validating the signature it tells me that it needs the revocation information from the timestamp certificate chain.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: If you like, you can email me (see my profile) and I try to find a solution. Of course best would be, to have a working example file, which you've created via Office manually.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I already sent you an email.